# Creating multipoint from point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, multipoint

I am quite new to PostGIS.

I need take some points from an existing table and create a multipoint and save this.

How would i go about this?

The only way i can think without creating a new table is:

```
Alter table
alter column geom TYPE geometry (MULTIPOINT,3857) USING ST_Multi(geom);
```

if i had to create a table what would the statement look like when using the x,y of the points in the point table?

Ive been asked to then find the centre of the mutlipoint, I know i need to use  ST_Centroid but what would the code look like?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: adressing your first question as the main: it´s a shot in the dark what to advise here as there is a plethora of options. first off: in general, I´d advise against converting single-geom-per-row into multi-geom-per-row in the same table and simply altering the column type wouldn´t get you anywhere. how do you determine which points to collect into a *MULTIPOINT*?

Comment: The table has only 10 points so i would be using all 10. I guess it would be better to create a new table?

Comment: seems silly for a input table that size, but IMO that would be the proper way, at least for robustness and ease of use, and also concerning the internal table statistics and the spatial index. you can always drop the other one if you don´t need it. one more thing: do those points have singular attributes that need to be aggregated (i.e. you are *collecting* geometries, thus reducing rows; you need to decide what to to with the other columns when those rows are reduced)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no aggregation of the points is required

Comment: Would i be best of just using the geomtery tool in QGIS to turn singlepart to multipart? (this is all for a training exercise i am doing so i can understand if what i am doing is a little silly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could do this:

> CREATE TABLE point_union
>   AS(SELECT
>   ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom))::geometry(MultiPoint, 3857) AS geom
>   FROM
>   your_table);
>
> CREATE TABLE center
>   AS(SELECT ST_Centroid(geom)
>   FROM point_union);

You then get a MultiPoint Layer `point_union` and a centroid layer `center` of  `point_union`.

EDIT: To clarify my answer, from what you described, I assumed you might be better of using ST_Union.